# Using package TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I'm trying to write this frame but I'm finding difficulties with the `tikz` package.

Can anybody help me please?

Here what I have written, I need to match the variables now:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plan du pricing}
\begin{itemize}
\item [$\bullet$] Evaluer un produit dérivé sensible au crédit de maturité $T$ : le processus de valeur à
l'instant $t < \tau < T$ est donné par :
{\footnotesize
\begin{equation*}
   V_{t}^{\Q,\H}=R_{t}\E_{\Q}\Big[C R_{T}^{-1}1_{\{\tau > T\}} + \int_t^T 1_{\{\tau >u\}} R_{u}^{-1}dG_{u}+ Z_{\tau}1_{\{\tau\leq T\}} R_{\tau}^{-1}\Big|\mathcal{H}_t\Big]
\end{equation*}
}
où,
\begin{itemize}
\item [$\diamond$] C ($\mathcal{F}_T$-mesurable): Le paiement à l'échéance $T$ (si $\tau \geq T$).
\item [$\diamond$] G ($\F$-adapté): Le paiement du dividende.
\item [$\diamond$] Z ($\F$-prévisible): Le paiement de récupération à l'instant de défaut $\tau$.
\item [$\diamond$] R: Le processus d'actualisation.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you already tried that shows us which difficulties you face?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code there. Don't try to post it in a comment (both because of the length restriction of comments and because all formatting is lost in comments)

Comment: This is not a minimal example. The code must start with `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: The simple answer is to use place \tikzmark in the text everywhere graphics appears (are lines terminiate) then draw everything using [remember picture, overlay, on background layer].  You don't need tikz to change colors.

Answer (score 1):

I guess John Kormylo is referring to the upcoming version of `tikzmark`. With the present version, one still needs to do what will later be done by `\tikzmarknode` by hand.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plan du pricing}
\begin{itemize}
\item [$\bullet$] Evaluer un produit dérivé sensible au crédit de maturité $T$ : le processus de valeur à
l'instant $t < \tau < T$ est donné par :
{\footnotesize
\begin{equation*}
   V_{t}^{Q,H}=R_{t}E_{Q}\Big[
   \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(C.base)]{\node[fill=blue!30](C){$C$};} 
   R_{T}^{-1}1_{\{\tau > T\}} + \int_t^T 1_{\{\tau >u\}} R_{u}^{-1}d
   \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(G.base)]{\node[ellipse,fill=red!30](G){$G_{u}$};} 
   + 
   \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(Z.base)]{\node[ellipse,fill=purple!30](Z){$Z_{\tau}$};} 
   1_{\{\tau\leq T\}} R_{\tau}^{-1}\Big|\mathcal{H}_t\Big]
\end{equation*}
}
où,
\begin{itemize}
\item [$\diamond$] C\tikzmark{C1} ($\mathcal{F}_T$-mesurable): Le paiement à l'échéance $T$ (si $\tau \geq T$).
\item [$\diamond$] G ($F$-adapté): Le paiement du dividende\tikzmark{G1}.
\item [$\diamond$] Z ($F$-prévisible): Le paiement de récupération à l'instant de défaut $\tau$\tikzmark{Z1}.
\item [$\diamond$] R: Le processus d'actualisation.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw (C) to[out=-90,in=0] ([yshift=3pt]pic cs:C1);
\draw (G) to[out=-90,in=0] ([yshift=3pt]pic cs:G1);
\draw (Z) to[out=-90,in=0] ([yshift=3pt]pic cs:Z1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, you had some presumably self-defined commands in like `\E` etc. Since I do not know their definition, I replaced them by `E` etc. If you would have uploaded an MWE with these definitions in, that would not have been necessary, and you won't have to restore the backslashes I removed.